# How to get the fresh request.auth.token of user in security rules when he sent request with old one

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm updating customClaims via auto trigger cloud function and am not able to access such new customClaims in security rules

I'm working on chat web app. with sending friend request feature and I want to limit the number of friends for each user so I use cloud function auto trigger when new document (conversation that define new friendship) get created then increase friendsNumber customclaims for been able to control the permission of limited friends, so each time user add friends friendsNumber get increase by 1, but in security rules I always got `request.auth.token.friendsNumber == 0`.

I know that the request was sent by old token and by forcerefresh I could get a new one. But that want works with me because I update friendsNumber customClaims via auto trigger cloud function.

Is there any methods to get latest token or a way to access such new customClaims?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client):

> After new claims are modified on a user via the Admin SDK, they are
>   propagated to an authenticated user on the client side via the ID
>   token in the following ways:
>
> - A user signs in or re-authenticates after the custom claims are modified. The ID token issued as a result will contain the latest
>     claims.
> - An existing user session gets its ID token refreshed after an older token expires.
> - An ID token is force refreshed by calling currentUser.getIdToken(true).

You will need to either force a refresh of the token, or wait out the period of time when the client app refreshes the token for itself.  Until then, any changes to the claims will not be visible in the client or in security rules.